# poner div al final de la pagina, despues de una tabla generada en php

Tags: html, css

hola intento poner un div al final de la pagina, le pongo la propiedad bottom:0px pero me la pone al final de la pagina que se ve, pero no al final de la pagina total:https://postimg.cc/XXxXsvXs
este es el codigo, el div que quiero que me aparezca al final es el de la clase "cuadrado_terminos". Y como digo con el bottom:0px; me aparece al final pero solo al final de lo que se ve de la pagina, de manera que si hago un scroll se me sube para arriba. Por cierto lo que inntento hacer no es un footer, sino tan solo que me aparezca ese div abajo de todo, despues de la tabla.
un saludo

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <!-- Si no se pone esto, las lineas del menú aparecen de otra manera -->
<HTML>
<HEAD><TITLE>Tienda muebles</TITLE></HEAD>

<style type="text/css">

body

.productos_mas_vendidos
 {
 width: 96%; 
 height: auto;
 border: black 1px solid; 
 top:1650px; 
 margin-left: auto; 
 margin-right: auto; 
 background-color: white; 
 position:absolute; 
 left:2px;
 right:2px;
 }

 .cuadrado_terminos
 {
 width: 100%; 
 height: 10em; 
 bottom:0px;
 top:2570px;
 border: black 1px solid;
 background-color:blue;
 position:absolute;
 left:0px;
 right:0px;

 }
</style>

<BODY>
<?php 
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "tienda") or die ("no se conecto"); //db es el nombre del manejador de la base de datos
?>

<div style="text-align:center" class="productos_mas_vendidos">
<table>
<?php 
$datos=mysqli_query($db,"select * from todos where mostrar='true'");
$n_columnas=4;
$n_filas=mysqli_num_rows($datos);
for($i=0;$i<$n_filas;$i+=$n_columnas)
{            
    echo("<tr>");
    for($j=0;$j<$n_columnas;$j++)
    {
        $fila =mysqli_fetch_array($datos);
        echo("<td><img src='".$fila["link"]."'></td>");  
    }
    echo("</tr>");
}
?>
</table>
</div>

<div style="text-align:center" class="cuadrado_terminos" ><h1>hola que tal</h1></div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

---

he hecho los cambios que me recomendaste y me quedo asi:

```
<div style="display: flex;flex-direction: column">
<div style="text-align:center" class="productos_mas_vendidos">

<table>
<?php 
$datos=mysqli_query($db,"select * from todos where mostrar=true");
$n_columnas=6;
$n_filas=mysqli_num_rows($datos);
for($i=0;$i<$n_filas;$i+=$n_columnas)
{            
    echo("<tr>");
    for($j=0;$j<$n_columnas;$j++)
    {
        $fila =mysqli_fetch_array($datos);
        if (!empty($fila["link"]))
        {
            echo("<td><img src='".$fila["link"]."'>".$fila["id"]."</td>");  
        }
        else 
        {
            echo("<td></td>");
        }
    }
    echo("</tr>");
}
?>
</table>

</div>



<div style="text-align:center" class="cuadrado_terminos" ><h1>hola que tal</h1>      </div>
</div>
<div style="text-align:center" class="cuadrado_registro"></div>
<div style="text-align:center" class="cuadrado_slide_1"></div>
<div style="text-align:center" class="cuadrado_slide_2"></div>
```

pero el cuadro (cuadrado terminos) me aparece enmedio en vez de al final:
https://postimg.cc/w1MLJmwh

Answer (score 2):

El problema que estás teniendo es que ambos divs `.productos_mas_vendidos` y `.cuadrado_terminos` tienen posición absoluta. Los elementos al tener posición absoluta, pierden su "espacio" como bloque y quedan absolutos a su padre relativo más cercano.

Si quieres lograr que `.cuadrado_terminos` quede después de `.productos_mas_vendidos`, deberían tener position: relative; y manejar su disposición con `flex` o `grid`.

Si por alguna razón, esos elementos deben quedar con posición absoluta, debes setear dinámicamente las alturas de los divs, con Javascript, por ejemplo. De esa forma, siempre aparecerá uno abajo de otro.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

- Envuelve al `div` de productos más vendidos y cuadrado terminos dentro de un contenedor padre
- Al `div` padre dale un `display: flex;`
- Para mantenerlo en columna al contenedor padre dale un `flex-direction: column;`
- Elimina la propiedad position así como el valor absoluto, eso está provocando que tú etiqueta HTML se salga del flujo regular y quede sobre puesta a los demás

Lo anterior generará que el `div` de abajo de la tabla siempre quede al final de todo el contenido, no le damos un alto al contenedor de la tabla pues este crecerá a medida que le llegue contenido de la base de datos.

Comment: he hecho los cambios que me recoendasta y me quedo asi:

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con la etiqueta

```
<footer>
   Aquí lo que va al fondo de la página
</footer>
```

Saludos.

Comment: no funciona, ademas no quiero hacer un footer, es decir no quiero que el div se vea en todo momento, solo quiero que aparezca al final de la pagina, algo tan sencillo como eso, no soy capaz de hacerlo.

Comment: ¿Por qué usar la etiqueta `<footer>` solucionaría el problema? La etiqueta en sí sólo proporciona valor semántico pero no cambia la visualización o posicionamiento del contenido.